# SQL Server possible to create temp table with all columns nullable automatically?

Tags: sql, sql-server

By using the following query, temporary table `testingTemp` will be created and the definition of columns are depending on `oriTable`.(I guess)

```
Select a.ID AS [a], 
       b.ID AS [b], 
       c.ID AS [c]
INTO #testingTemp
FROM
oriTable
```

And I have my second query as below:

```
Insert into #testingTemp (c)
Select z.ID AS [c]
FROM
oriTable
```

Now when I execute second query, SQL Server complaint

```
Cannot insert the value NULL into column 'a' , table 'tempdb.dbo.testingTemp...blabla
```

**May I know how to solve this problem without changing `oriTable` structure?**

Comment: have you tried creating the #testingTemp table? like CREATE TABLE #testingTemp(a int null, b int null, c int null) ?

Comment: @Marciano.Andrade: I'm looking for alternatives because the real scenario is my first query will actually select tons of columns. I don't want to define the column myself if there is any alternatives?

Comment: If the values contain NULL, the column will be nullable as well. So perhaps you can just add a union of nulls to your data before the insert into.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use

```
SELECT ID + 0 AS [a],
       ID + 0 AS [b],
       ID + 0 AS [c]
INTO   #testingTemp
FROM   oriTable
```

The nullability of columns computed via an expression is almost always assumed to be `NULL` rather than `NOT NULL`

Comment: I believe it is better to use ID + '' since it will not conflict with varchar. Was about to post it when i saw your answer

Comment: @t-clausen.dk - Good point. I just assumed `ID` was likely `int` (probably after seeing Marciano's comment) but then again it could be uniqueidentifier for all we know and the expression would need to change again!

Comment: @t-clausen.dk - Just tested it. Would need to be `COALESCE(ID,NULL)`. My original thought of `COALESCE(ID,ID)` gets simplified out.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
ALTER TABLE #testingTemp ALTER COLUMN [a] int NULL
```

Answer (score 0):

Try This :

During first insert try to convert the columns with constraint (primary key or not null) to their respective data types.

```
Select convert(int,a.ID) AS [a], 
       b.ID AS [b], 
       c.ID AS [c]
INTO #testingTemp
FROM
oriTable
```

since we used convert function the constraint structure (primary or not null constraint) is not copied to the temp table.
and now you can gently fire the second insert statement and it will execute without any error.

```
Insert into #testingTemp (c)
Select z.ID AS [c]
FROM
oriTable
```